# How i can make this to send the post data?

Tags: bootstrapper

There is a bootstrap navbar modal element with form, and it doesnt send the data if i click to sign in, i trying but cant find a solution, anyone can help to me?

https://jsfiddle.net/syndw8uL/

```
<!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <!-- Modal Header -->
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Customer Sign In</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal body, why not work here the action?-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="/action_page.php" method = "post">


                        <label class="sr-only" for="usrname">Username</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">

                        </div>


                        <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Name</label>
                        <div class="input-group mb-2">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <!-- Modal footer -->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Sign In</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You submit button `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Sign In</button>` is outside your form.  Place the button inside form element it should work.